# duel of 3 people shooting

Tags: probability

$3$ people $A,B,C$ are shooting each other. The chance that $A$ will hit in a single shot is $0.2$,
The chance for $B$ to hit is $0.3$ and for $C$ is $0.1$.

If one hit a person, he will continue to hit until he'll be the last one.

What is the chance for each one of the people $A,B,C$ to be alive?

I think that $A$ will be alive if he shot $B$ and $B$ will miss him. Also $A$ hit $C$ and $C$ will miss him.
But I think it's more complex than that and I'm confused.

I'd glad if someone can clear this question for me.

Thanks.

Comment: Say A is shooting, who will he aim for first? Also who shoots first?

Comment: It doesn't say who will shot first I guess it's $A$.